# BigCommerce's Optimized One-Page Checkout Mutilingual Limitations

Tags: bigcommerce

BigCommerce's [Optimized One-Page Checkout](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Optimized-Single-Page-Checkout?language=en_US) allows some multi-lingual support. However, the language that is presented is decided based on the user's browser locale with no way for a user to manually override.

Why? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of localization in the Optimized One Page Checkout. I personally have not implemented a workaround but others may have tried to and can share here, if so.